# Multiple calls to jar main file inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm seeing 8 calls to the output stream, is docker container creating multiple instances of the jar file?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("main");
}
```

output

```
main
main
main
main
main
main
main
```

docker-compose file

```
department:
    image: openjdk:jdk-alpine
    container_name: "department"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9082:8080
      - 65195:65193
    volumes:
      - ./Dept/target/Dept-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/deployments/Dept-jar-with-dependencies.jar
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:65193,suspend=n,server=y -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    command: java -jar /deployments/Dept-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `restart: always`, whenever the container exits, it will immediately be restarted.  Also, since the main container process is what you've put into this jar, every time `main()` completes the container will be restarted.

If you're actively developing this, I'd suggest first trying to get the application work in a non-Docker context, then packaging it up.  A more typical restart policy is `restart: on-failure`, which won't restart the container if it exits normally (with status code 0).  Also consider packaging up this set of options into a `Dockerfile` so that it can be run without separately needing the jar file.